# Javascript: Looping through a promise within an object

Tags: javascript

So currently I'm trying to loop through a return (API says it returns an object that has a promise within it)

API: https://github.com/sentanos/roblox-js/wiki/Main-Functions

My Code thus far:

```
var rbx = require('roblox-js');

      rbx.login('INF_BOT', '$$$')
      .then(function (info) {
      console.log('Logged in with ID ' + info.userId)
    })
      .catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err.stack);
    });

  var Players = rbx.getPlayers(539310, 1, false, -2)


for (var plr in Players) {
   console.log(plr);
}
```

I have never seen a promise helped within a object nor do I know how to go through the promise to get the returned players. The API linked above says what I mean under the function getPlayers()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is before the promise from login action is fulfilled, you tried to call getPlayers().  At this time, rbx object has not been authenticated yet.  In other words, the promise is fulfilled some time in the future asynchronously whereas the call to getPlayers() happens right after login() synchronously.  So to fix the code, you can call getPlayers() when the promise is fulfilled, i.e. inside the then clause:

```
var rbx = require('roblox-js');

rbx.login('INF_BOT', '$$$')
  .then(function (info) {
    console.log('Logged in with ID ' + info.userId);
    var Players = rbx.getPlayers(539310, 1, false, -2);
    for (var plr in Players) {
      console.log(plr);
    }
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
  });
```

Also verify getPlayers() returns a promise which is more than likely, then call it in the same way as login().

Answer (score 0):

The loop would have to be placed inside the .then function...*something like* this likely non-executable example...for example. Otherwise you attempt to access data that may not yet be present.

```
var rbx = require('roblox-js');

  rbx.login('INF_BOT', '$$$')
  .then(function (info) {
      console.log('Logged in with ID ' + info.userId)
      rbx.getPlayers(539310, 1, false, -2).promise.then(function(Players){
          for (var plr in Players) {
           console.log(plr);
          }
      });        
    });
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
  console.error(err.stack);
});
```

You would have to look at the API to determine if the collection you want is passed to .then() or not. But this is the general pattern. There are lots of other ways to structure it, depending on your needs.

This assumes that getPlayers() returns a promise.

Comment: # TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'then'

Comment: Yes, this is not supposed to be executable. It's an answer to the question about how to structure code to use a returned promise. I have no idea whether a promise is actually returned by this API. If it has no .then() it's not a promise, and OP's question is based on false assumptions. Looks like roblox documentation suggests a promise is not returned but instead an object {promise:, getStatus:}